# How to create array of images, and use draw() to draw them out in Swift?

Tags: swift, nsarray

I am trying to figure out how to create a 'map' using an array of images.
I can draw out one image fine using f.draw(at:imagePoint) , but when I try to draw out an array of the images, I am not able to. How do I set up the array of images, and then draw out the array that I have specified?

```
  var loc = CGPoint(x: 50, y:30)
    //variables to hold the separate pictures
    let f = UIImage(named: "forest.png")!
    var m = UIImage(named: "mountain.png")!
    let o = UIImage(named: "out.png")!
    let p = UIImage(named: "plain.png")!
    let t = UIImage(named: "treasure.png")!
    let w = UIImage(named: "water.png")!
    let person = UIImage(named: "person.png")!

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        //create array of the referenced images
        let tileMap = [o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,
                       o,m,m,f,f,f,p,p,p,p,w,o,
                       o,m,m,f,f,f,p,p,p,p,w,o,m]

        print("draw called")
        var imagePoint = CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0)
        //display map
        //tileMap.draw(at: imagePoint)

        for element in tileMap{
            element.draw(at: imagePoint)
            //imagePoint = CGPoint(x:0,y:0)
            //how to increment CGPoint for each image?

        }

        //display person
        person.draw(at:loc)
    }
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense. You can't say `draw` to an array.

Comment: What would be an alternative way to draw out each image to form 'tiles'?

Comment: Go thru the array and draw each image into its place in the grid, one at a time.

Comment: I edited it because I am trying to loop through instead, how would I change the CGPoint for each image? Sorry am new to this.

Comment: try to use collectionView to show all your images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be this can be help full to you :=

```
    let tileMap = [o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,
                   o,m,m,f,f,f,p,p,p,p,w,o,
                   o,m,m,f,f,f,p,p,p,p,w,o,m]

    print("draw called")

    let row = 5

    let numberOfInRow = tileMap.count / row

    let xWidth = Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.width) / numberOfInRow
    let yHeight = Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.height) / row

    var xPoint = 0
    var yPoint = 0

    var itemCountInRow = 0

    for element in tileMap{

        let imagePoint = CGPoint(x: xPoint,y: yPoint)
        element.draw(at: imagePoint)

        if(numberOfInRow > itemCountInRow){
            itemCountInRow += 1
            xPoint += xWidth
        }else{
            itemCountInRow = 0
            xPoint = 0
            yPoint += yHeight
        }
    }
```